# Distance checkbox controls lose value after search companies link is clicked

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

Steps to reproduce...

1. Click search companies
2. Hover over location and click the allows remote / offers relocation / offers visa sponsorship checkboxes (or click all three of them)
3. Pick any job
4. Click the search companies tab yet again

Filter is gone, I was hoping it would stay.

Comment: Note: the up/down arrows on my keyboard allow me to navigate through the dropdown, but I also cannot do this using the mouse.

Answer (score -1):

I can't say why, but it's by-design. It's nothing we ever considered, but we're willing to re-visit it in the future.

Comment: You can't say because somebody doesn't want you to, or you can't say because there isn't actually a reason?

Comment: @DamienH There's no reason. It was a decision made years ago and we've just stuck to it.